# Protobuf type inheritance with WCF

Tags: wcf, protobuf-net

We have trouble with the protobuf-net type inheritance.

We have a base class like this:

```
[DataContract, ProtoContract]
public abstract class BaseClass : IBase
{
protected IBase()
{
    RequestUID = Guid.NewGuid();
}

[DataMember(Order = 8000), ProtoMember(8000)]
public Guid ID { get; set; }

[DataMember(Order = 8001), ProtoMember(8001)]
public string User { get; set; }
```

}

And classes which inherits from BaseClass.

```
[DataContract, ProtoContract]
public class ConcreteClass : BaseClass
{
[DataMember(Order = 4), ProtoMember(4)]
public int? WorkItemId { get; set; }
}
```

(In future we are going to use only ProtoMember and ProtoContract.)

When the client and server starts we do following in both environments:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(BaseClass)].AddSubType(50, typeof(ConcreteClass));
```

Now when we pass an instance of ConcreteClass to a WCF service operation we get exceptions:

- BaseClass does not provide a public constructor. (Wrong type chosen for deserialization)
- Or if we provide a public constructor for BaseClass it tries to cast the BaseClass object to ConcreteClass on the server. (Again wrong type)
- And under some special circumstances (we don't know exactly when this happens) Protobuf tries to deserialize from **OtherConcreteClass** to **ConcreteClass**.

What are we doing wrong? The WCF behavior is register correctly. We had no problems with simple classes (no inheritance).

Is there and documentation how two configure the inheritance properly for WCF scenarios?

Thanks

Comment: This is more an alternative way to do it than an answer:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541392/is-there-a-better-way-of-using-protobuf-in-a-wcf-service-without-the-drawbacks?answertab=votes

Comment: Hi Sumit. The link is wrong.